# MySQL generated with EF returns "error in your SQL syntax" in LinQ for FromSqlRaw in selecting vars from system

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I had the following SQL call in ASP NET Core 3.1 to get some configurations of the server. In this case, for any e.g., the `event scheduler` (MySQL Database)

```
_context.Set<Event_Scheduler>().FromSqlRaw("SELECT @@event_scheduler as event_configuration;").FirstOrDefault();
```

That returns a record with a single varchar ("ON") and then it maps to this class:

```
public class Event_Scheduler { 
    public string event_configuration { get; set; }
}
```

Also included in the context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Event_Scheduler>().HasNoKey();
```

I'm not seeing the whole thing here or I need more coffee.
Any help or tip will be grateful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please oh please share the full error stack.

Comment: Add AsEnumerable() after the call to FromSqlRaw

Comment: @ErikEJ thanks a lot!!!!! :S what the .... !!!! would you like to answer in order I can vote and mark your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add AsEnumerable() after the call to FromSqlRaw, instead of composing over it right away.